# Issue with z-index in child/parent elements

Tags: css, z-index

I'm not much a z-index user, and I've read around the web that many issues with z-index are other elements not having the right properties. Unforunately I'm not good at that either! Anyhow, the code is here: [jsfiddle.net/B3N2Q](http://jsfiddle.net/B3N2Q/).

As you can see, there's multiple divs on the page with content. When the inside of a div is clicked (or edited as a matter of fact, but thats no biggy), a save button should appear. Looking at the fiddle, you can see that the button is also visible when it should be behind the parent div.

I've been able to or get it in front of everything the whole time, or hidden the whole time (if I use a `z-index=-20;` or so.

Now, the question is how do I get the button to be hidden before the onclick event, and visible when sliding down? So that it appears as if it's a tab that gets slid down.

Comment: a lot of times you need to make sure the divs have a position element, usually position: relative;

Comment: If you take a look at the code,  you can see they are positioned with `position: relative;`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell what your question is

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Sorry about that, edited it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element cannot be behind the parent element. It is always on top of it regardless the z-index that you assigned to it.

You should move your buttons outside the div's to have z-index applied properly. And set the background for your div as by default they are transparent:

```
<div>
    <div style='position: relative; border:1px solid black; background-color: white; padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;width:896px; height: 200px;z-index:50;'>
      your content here
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="button" style='width:100px;margin: -35px auto;'>
        <input type='button' style='border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0px;border-top-right-radius:0px;' value='save' title='save this shit' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uYGEd/1/

Answer (score 1):

A child element can't appear behind its parent unless it's absolutely positioned regardless of what the `z-index` is.  Solutions for hiding the Save buttons are pretty simple, though.  You can just have it `display: none` and have it `slideDown` when it's to become visible.  Another solution would be to have the Save button in a separate div from its container so you can use `z-index` appropriately, but I think that would be more complicated.

Comment: The slideDown seems to do the job, but it's a pretty weird effect though... It looks a little strange. http://jsfiddle.net/B3N2Q/1/

Comment: @arbitter maybe the separate div solution would be for you then

Comment: Got it to work, I had also forgotten to set the `background-color: white;` of the covering element.